# Does Inno Setup's ExpandConstant support UTF-8?

Tags: inno-setup

I have an Inno Setup installer that creates custom wizard pages using Pascal Script.  The installer appears to use the proper patterns for supporting other languages.  However, the custom wizard pages, created with `CreateCustomPage()`, show garbage characters in them, instead of the strings in the target language (which in this case, is Russian.)

The strings are stored in a `[CustomMessages]` section, using include files for each language.  Though I'm a newbie with Inno Setup, the strings do appear to be set up in a manner that is consistent with the Inno Setup examples, and with instructions I've read from various sources on the internet.

Anyway, the custom wizard pages and the controls on them are created using code such as:

```
Page := CreateCustomPage(
  PreviousPageId,
  ExpandConstant('{cm:MyStringConstant}'),
  ExpandConstant('{cm:MyOtherStringConstant}')
);
```

Then, in the strings include file (again, for Russian), the strings are defined as:

```
[CustomMessages]
ru.MyStringConstant=<Russian string>
ru.MyOtherStringConstant=<Russian string>
```

But when the installer runs, the strings on the custom wizard pages appear with garbage characters (as if the UTF-8 characters are being interpreted as Ansi), rather than in the proper Russian text.

The other pages in the installer (ie, those not created with `CreateCustomPage()`) appear correctly.

So, my question is, does something special need to be done when using `ExpandConstant()` with UTF-8 strings?  Or is there a better function to use to retrieve UTF-8 strings from the `[CustomMessages]` section?

Comment: are you using Unicode inno setup?

Comment: Yes, I am using the Unicode version.  The problem was a missing BOM character in the localized strings file.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

As long as you're running the unicode version of the Inno Compiler, then UTF-8 is supported in the main ISS file. You CAN NOT use UTF-8 or any unicode format in the ISL language files as these must be in ANSI with the appropriate codepage specified.

You must also use unicode character literals to specify unicode text in the `[Code]` section.

See the [Unicode Inno Setup article in the help file for details](http://www.jrsoftware.org/ishelp/topic_unicode.htm).

Comment: Thanks.  The problem turned out to be that the include file containing the localized strings was missing a BOM character at the beginning.  Once I added the BOM character, it worked like a champ.

Comment: So, afterall it is possible to use *.isl localization files encoded in UTF-8 ?

Comment: @TLama: Sorry, I guess I should have clarified this in the original post: these aren't .isl files, but merely .iss files that are #include'd.  Sorry if I got your hopes up. :-)

Comment: @TLama. No, ISL files MUST be in a non Unicode codepage specified int he header of the file itself.

Comment: The recent versions of Inno Setup support (undocumented) `.islu` localization files that use UTF-8. See [Is it safe to use .islu translation files in Inno Setup for all languages?](http://stackoverflow.com/q/28449428/850848).

Comment: In the article, they speak of the LanguageCodePage (variable, define ???) to set a correct interpretation of a isl file. Ca it be a solution? Why has inno not patched to support Unicode everywhere? Why is my .iss on a Unicode Inno stil in ANSI?

Comment: @Sandburg it's a directive in the header of the `isl` file. It can not be used anywhere else.