# Is it safe to use .islu translation files in Inno Setup for all languages?

Tags: unicode, encoding, inno-setup

I'm using Inno Setup for my open source project WinSCP.
So far I'm generating Inno Setup `.isl` translation files from our project-specific translation files (particularly to translate `CustomMessages` section).

But the `.isl`'s need to be converted to ANSI encoding. There's a problem with ANSI encoding for languages that does not have an ANSI encoding at all (like Hindi or Armenian) or whose ANSI encoding is limited (like Romanian).

I see that core Inno Setup translations for some languages use `.islu` extension, (probably) indicating that the contents is UTF-8 encoded. I can also see in the Inno Setup source code that the `.islu`'s are used in Unicode version of Inno Setup only. That's ok, as I'm using Unicode version only.

But I did not find any mention of `.islu` in documentation.

Is it OK if I generate just `.islu`'s for all languages? Is there any drawback (apart from inability to use the ANSI version of Inno Setup)?

Or should I keep using `.isl` for languages with good ANSI encoding, and use `.islu` just for selected languages?

I'd obviously prefer the first to simplify the process.

---

Also what `LanguageCodePage` should be set to for `.islu`? The official Nepali translation uses 0. Not sure if that's a general rule for `.islu` or it's because Nepali does not have an ANSI encoding.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

After few months of using this, I can confirm that adding the UTF-8 BOM and using the `.islu` extension for all Inno Setup translations seems to work well.

---

The `.islu` files are [documented since Inno Setup 5.5.9](https://github.com/jrsoftware/issrc/commit/75b5bce5c0c7cc3023bc54d18d13aa8675d2549a):

> If no code page currently exists for the language, set `LanguageCodePage` to 0, use a special .islu extension for the language's file, and encode this file as Unicode. Note: this makes your language file unusable by Non Unicode Inno Setup so only do this if really needed. Also note: a `LanguageName` setting in a .islu file does not need to use the special "<nnnn>" encoding mentioned above.