# Buttons are being cropped on Inno Setup install and a custom message is showing in gibberish (for Japanese)

Tags: inno-setup

In my `[run]` section I have this entry:

```
Filename: "{win}\hh.exe"; \
    Parameters: "{app}\MeetSchedAssist.chm::/msa-revision-history.htm"; \
    WorkingDir: "{app}"; \
    Flags: nowait postinstall runmaximized; \
    Description: "{cm:ViewChangeHistory}"
```

When I run my installer in **English** it looks fine:

[image: Results in English]

A user has just recorded a video installing it on a **Japanese** computer:

[image: Results in Japanese]

There are two issues:

1. The buttons of the GUI are all **cropped**.
2. The "View Change History" custom string is **gibberish**.

The **English** custom messages file (UTF-8 encoded) has:

```
English.ViewChangeHistory=View Change History
```

The **Japanese** custom messages file (UTF-8 encoded) has:

```
Japanese.ViewChangeHistory=変更履歴を表示
```

Why is it not displaying correctly? I am using the most recent version of Inno Setup Unicode. I do know that the user is using a Ultra HD monitor.

Also, I am rebuilding the run list like this:

```
type
  TRunEntry = record
    Caption: string;
    Checked: Boolean;
    Object: TObject;
  end;

procedure RebuildRunList;
var
  RunEntries: array of TRunEntry;
  I: Integer;
begin
  // Save run list ...
  SetArrayLength(RunEntries, WizardForm.RunList.Items.Count);
  for I := 0 to WizardForm.RunList.Items.Count - 1 do
  begin
    RunEntries[I].Caption := WizardForm.RunList.ItemCaption[I];
    RunEntries[I].Checked := WizardForm.RunList.Checked[I];
    RunEntries[I].Object := WizardForm.RunList.ItemObject[I];
  end;

  // ... clear it ... 
  WizardForm.RunList.Items.Clear;

  // ... and re-create 
  for I := 0 to GetArrayLength(RunEntries) - 1 do
  begin
    // the first three entries are radio buttons 
    if (I = 0) or (I = 1) or (I = 2) then
    begin
      WizardForm.RunList.AddRadioButton(
        RunEntries[I].Caption, '', 0, RunEntries[I].Checked, True, RunEntries[I].Object);
    end
      else
    begin
      WizardForm.RunList.AddCheckBox(
        RunEntries[I].Caption, '', 0, RunEntries[I].Checked, True, True, True,
        RunEntries[I].Object);
    end;
  end;
end;

procedure CurPageChanged(CurPageID: Integer);
begin
  if CurPageID = wpFinished then
  begin
    // Only now is the RunList populated.
    // Two entries are on 64-bit systems only.
    if IsWin64 then RebuildRunList;
  end;
end;
```

## Update

I commented out the code that rebuilds the run list and it made no difference on my PC:

[image: Results 1]

However, the skinning works correctly. So the button position matter must be related to the users using a ultra HD configuration and and/or scaled text.

Then I commentted out the skinning code and tried again on my PC. No change:

[image: Results 2]

I really don't understand why this is happening!

## Update

I include the custom messages like this:

```
[CustomMessages]
#include AddBackslash(SourcePath) + ".\l.jpn\CustomMessagesJapanese.txt"
```

Comment: Is this happening without that skinning mechanism? Just to exclude it as a source of problem.

Comment: Have you tried commenting out the code that rebuilds the run list?  You claimed to have done that above but the screenshot shows an obviously still rebuilt list.

Comment: @Miral I wondered that as well. But it turns out that was not the problem anyway - as you alluded to in your answer / comments I had to change the encoding to `UTF-8 BOM`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This depends on how you're including the text.

### In an ISL file with MessagesFile

According to http://www.jrsoftware.org/ishelp/topic_unicode.htm, it is not legal to save an ISL file in UTF-8.

You must save it as ANSI encoded with the code page specified in the file.

### Directly in your ISS file or using #include

Alternatively you can use UTF-8 strings directly in your iss file by using Language.Key values directly in a local [Messages] or [CustomMessages] section, like so:

```
[CustomMessages]
English.ViewChangeHistory=View Change History
Japanese.ViewChangeHistory=変更履歴を表示
```

You can also #include an external file that uses the same format.

In both cases (whether directly in the iss file or in a #included file), you need to ensure that the file is saved as UTF-8 with BOM.

Comment: This is not a ISL file. This is a text file that gets included for the comments for Japanese.

Comment: I use the #include statement.

Comment: Are you saying that any text file that is #include into the custom messages section needs to be ANSI? That is a nightmare if so. I have up to 50 languages. If I can directly have the Unicode strings in the ISS file then why not when I include them? I will test later on by putting the text directing in the script as per your answer. Thanks. Will update you.

Comment: No, #include files can be UTF-8, as long as they are UTF-8 with BOM.  The ANSI limitation applies to ISL files included with the MessagesFile directive.  You did not actually specify how you were doing this in your original question.

Comment: No I didnt. I will update later and do more tests. How do I confirm my utf file has bom?

Comment: If you use vanilla Notepad, use File-Save As and select UTF-8 as the Encoding; it will always use a BOM.
If you use some other editor it may have a setting somewhere else; for example Notepad++ shows "UTF-8" or "UTF-8 without BOM" in the status bar and you can change it in the Encoding menu.

Comment: Please update your answer so I can accept it. The reason was because the file was UTF-8 and not UTF-8 BOM. Now it is fine. Thanks. :)

Comment: @AndrewTruckle Ok, updated.

Comment: For `.isl`: You can use UTF-8 if you switch to `.islu`: https://stackoverflow.com/q/28449428/850848

Comment: @MartinPrikryl That's interesting, and thanks, since I was unaware of it.  The documentation seems a bit misleading, as it's written from a perspective of doing a completely new language (which is not the case here), and implies you need to set LanguageCodePage=0, which is both false and a bad idea (since it will break any inherited isl files with a different value).